# Redis - Reliable queue pattern with multiple pops in one request

Tags: redis

I have implemented [Redis's reliable queue pattern](https://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) using BRPOPLPUSH because I want to avoid polling.

However this results in a network request for each item. How can I augment this so that a worker BRPOPLPUSH'es multiple entries at once?

Comment: The question does not compile for me - what does it mean to pop multiple entries at once?

Comment: @ItamarHaber something like BRPOPLPUSH src dest count

Comment: So wait until there are at least `count` to pop? At most? Exactly? How does this make sense if there are concurrent blocking clients?

Answer (score 0):

While [BRPOPLPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/brpoplpush) is blocking version of [RPOPLSPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) and [do not support transactions](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/4091) and you can`t handle multiple entries. Also you can`t use LUA for this purposes because of LUA execution nature: server would be blocked for new requests before LUA script has finished.

You can use application side logic to resolve queue pattern you need. Pseudo language

```
func MyBRPOPLPUSH(source, dest, maxItems = 1, timeOutTime = 0) { 
   items = []
   timeOut = time() + timeOutTime
   while ((timeOut > 0 && time() < timeOut) || items.count < maxItems) {
      item = redis.RPOPLSPUSH(source, dest)
      if (item == nil) {
         sleep(someTimeHere);
         continue;
      }
      items.add(item)
}
```